# Hollandaise or Bernaise?

Tags: sauce, hollandaise

It's my understanding that once you add any herbs to Hollandaise that it is no longer Hollandaise but Bearnaise?

Is this a correct assumption?

Answer (score 1):

Bearnaise is based on hollandaise (hollandaise being one of the 5 French mother sauces).  Yes, it is an egg yolk-butter emulsion with the addition of herbs.  Personally, I would say that it is a *version* of a hollandaise.

Comment: I was at a restaurant where they had eggs benedict and said their sauce was hollandaise. When it came there was a ton of Rosemary and Thyme in the hollandaise, so much so that it made it unpalatable to me. The sauce resembled nothing like Hollandaise but more of a Bernaise that would be good on steak or poultry.

Comment: Strangely, Joe Bastianich once said that the French never eat béarnaise with steak, which is strange because I've always thought they are a classic pairing.